# Is it possible to enable SSRS to an existing TFS 2010 installation?

Tags: tfs

I believe one of the options on the installation of TFS 2010 is to enable SSRS (for web portal reports etc.). I think our existing installation of TFS was installed without this option - is there a way to enable this post installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems we were seeing was due to having TFS Server installed on a machine with Windows 7 as the OS. Having found a site that suggested that these features will only work on a Server OS, I installed TFS onto Windows Server 2008, and the features were available.

Answer (score 1):

None of the reports (web or otherwise) work without SSRS.  Quite frankly I wasn't aware it was even possible to install TFS without SSRS.

You might want to check this out further. Most likely the security just wasn't setup correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the guide here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380714.aspx and I can not see any reports icon, therefore I assumed that I had not got SSRS installed / Configured. I have admin rights, which is another thing it suggests you need.

Comment: @Ben: That is a side effect of either your account not having appropriate permissions or it's not correctly configured.  Check out the TFS Installation guide and walk through checking all of the details.  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2d531219-2c39-4c69-88ef-f5ae6ac18c9f